# Failed to send an EMail with body contains ip address and port no

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I have create function to send an email. This function was work successful on localhost but on server its failed without any exception. I know the problem comes from my **Port** on **IP Address**.

The sample body is `string body = "<p>Please click <a href=\"http://123.10.10.10:9200/User/Test?userId=24c04b9e-5a32-4b7c-a61e-ea3303dac679\">here</a></p>Thank You."`

The problem is `:` between **IP Address** and **Port**.

Successful send an email if i remove `:`.

Do you guys have any ideas?

```
public void Sent(string sender, string receiver, string subject, string body)
    {
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sender, receiver))
        {
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Port = 25;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Host = "mail.companyName.com.my";
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = body;
                client.Send(mail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean that successful delivery of the mail depends on the body content? Is the only clue you have that the mail is not delivered to the recipient, or do you have access to the smtp server and can view its logs? Specify a return address and see if that smtp server bounces a delivery failure. And try a different smtp server too.

Comment: Yes that's it. Other body was successful except the sample on the top. I need to used my company smtp.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is a filter somewhere on the delivery route, which discards mails based on content rules. Then the problem is most likely not with your code. It is indeed possible to deliver mails which contain a non-standard-port-URL in their html body, we do it all the time.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question, so @dlatikay comment must be your best guess. The issue is indeed your server using a different port number. In that case, add another `int Port` parameter to your method and set '25' as its default value. `public void Sent(string sender, string receiver, string subject, string body, int port = 25)`, then change the method call signature when calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, the code to send the mail is ok (you may want to revise the function name and make the smtp host name configurable, but that is not the point here).

The e-mail delivery fails on a relay, there is no immedieate feedback (no exception) to the client about this kind of failure.

The best bet is the `IncreaseScoreWithRedirectToOtherPort` property set in `Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy` in case your mail provider is Office365, or a similar spam filter mechanism in any other mail provider that is encountered down the mail delivery chain.

You can set a `reply-to` address and hope that the destination server will bounce a delivery failure that gives you more information. Or have the admin of the mail server look up the logs. More information here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/659861/office-365-exchange-online-any-way-to-block-false-url-spam

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the 'mail.Body' to receive a Raw Html message instead of a encoded string, like:

```
mail.Body = new System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(new System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext(), new System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage()).Raw(body).ToString();
```

Or put a `using System.Web.Mvc` at the beginning so it gets shorter and easier to understand:

```
using System.Web.Mvc

mail.Body = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage()).Raw(body).ToString();
```